# phpmyadmin 5.2.1 from Debian 12 fatal error with php7.4

Tags: phpmyadmin

After downgrading from php8.2 to php7.4 (from sury-repository) on Debian 12 phpmyadmin does not work anymore with following entry in error.log:

`AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\array_is_list() in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:1092`

I installed phpmyadmin via 'apt install phpmyadmin' and it shows me version 5.2.1 with the hint 'PHP 7.2.5+ is required' (in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php) so there should be no problems with php7.4 in general.

But reviewing the error taking a look to the line 1092 in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:

`if (!array_is_list($arguments)) {`

Asking php.net for the function 'array_is_list':

```
(PHP 8 >= 8.1.0)
array_is_list — Checks whether a given array is a list
```

So, I guess there is something wrong. Either the phpmyadmin from Debian 12 is not the version it maintains or version 5.2.1 does not work on PHP < 8.1.0.

What version do I really need to get it work on php7.4?

Answer (score 0):

I install phpmyadmin5.0.1 with php 7.4 on debian12. It's work ! I had the same problem like you.
Have a good day

Comment: How did you install phpmyadmin 5.0.1 on Debian 12? Did you use a repository? The cause of the incompatibility seems to be the version of Symfony that is installed with "apt install phpmyadmin" on Debian 12 using commands that are not known in php7.4. Did you substitute Symfony too?